# User group (company) page that shows summary of all user accounts belonging to the same company/user group

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, user-accounts

For example, on LinkedIn when you say that you work for some company, then it's possible to have link to that company name that will list all employees with links to their profiles.

Is something similar possible on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange? I.e. have a short cut to a page which displays account summary for all user who said they are working for IBM or Microsoft or myconsultingcompany.com?

Comment: But then we'd start expecting them to act in an official capacity. Which if you're paid by Google to do Android support here is probably a good thing, but if you're a Microsoft employee answering general questions you'd have to constantly say "my opinions are my own, not my employer's", etc.

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich - What value would this add? What benefit would this bring to the content on SO?

Comment: @McDowell, may be it will not be useful for SO content, but it may be useful for the companies willing to promote themselves and showing how their employees are involved into certain technical communities. I'm not sure if it will bring any benefit for improving content on SO, but it may potentially bring more people to SO.

Comment: @Rup, may be microsoft is not really a good example for this feature usage :) but smaller companies or open-source backing companies may actually benefit from that feature.

Comment: After all, it does not need to be bound to companies, it can be just any user group that declare themselves as one entity.

Comment: Naturally, user can be part of many user groups

Comment: This question needs more attention.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a nice idea, but with some down-sides.

For example:  A customer support site has their employees answer questions on here to boost their company page, thus promoting the business; but this also leaves space for companies and employees to spam short or meaningless answers, so the company page looks better based on activity alone.

Comment: if user declares himself to belong to some company you can actually prohibit to vote for co-workers. there is already some background scripts that exist in SO that catch mass-upvote or mass-downvote coming from the same user. The same principle can be applied for the company employee voting.

Comment: or alterntivaely the company page can show the rating coming from non-employees and rating coming from employees to just compare on how honest is the company.

Comment: These are both excellent ideas.