# Should we burninate the [groups] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

I recently found out that Meta Stack Exchange has a [groups](/questions/tagged/groups) tag. It has 9 questions and no tag wiki or excerpt, and really doesn't add any useful information to questions. On most (not all) questions, [groups](/questions/tagged/groups) can be replaced by [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) or [notifications](/questions/tagged/notifications).

Should we burninate the [groups](/questions/tagged/groups) tag in place of more useful tags, or am I missing a reason to keep it?

(While there are just 9 questions with [groups], I don't want to remove the tag from all of them and then find out that the tag should be kept, thus I'm asking this question first.)

Comment: Several of the questions could use a [user-group(s)] tag.  [groups] doesn't help or is too vague/overloaded otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This request has had approval for almost a year despite the tag previously only having 9 questions.

There were only 4 instances ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141508/how-can-stack-overflow-be-used-as-a-collaborative-tool), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115259/strategies-to-draw-in-experts-from-walled-communities), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90763/user-group-company-page-that-shows-summary-of-all-user-accounts-belonging-to-t), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109665/so-or-se-user-groups-is-this-a-good-idea)) of this tag remaining.  With the help of [Luuklag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/361484/luuklag), the tag has been removed from all of them. Question numbers 1 and 2 needed some more definitive tags, which Luuklag handled.

[groups](/questions/tagged/groups) has been burninated, this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).